# Count each unique content

Tags: sql-server

How do I count how many times the content of a field `name`appears in my table?

```
Name    | Other
Brad    | smth
Brad    | smth
Daniel  | smth
Matt    | smth
Matt    | smth
Matt    | smth
```

For example,for the above table I would like to know how many times I have 'Brad',how many times 'Daniel' and how many times 'Matt'.How do I do this with just one select?
I'm interested in this because I want do display only the Names that appear more times than a given value.

My actual code:

```
select director.LastName,director.FirstName,count(director.FirstName)as counter,film.title
from director,film
where film.Id_Director=director.id 
group by director.LastName,director.FirstName,film.title
having  count(Director.FirstName)>2

    Baz Luhrmann    1   Paranormal activity 4
    Baz Luhrmann    1   Struck by lightning
    Baz Luhrmann    1   The big bang theory
    Baz Luhrmann    1   The family
    Baz Luhrmann    1   The Quarterback
    Brad Falchuk    1   A Kitty or a Gaga
    Brad Falchuk    1   All or nothing
    Brad Falchuk    1   Bridesmaids
    Brian   Dan     1   All or nothing
```

I was expecting it to count exactly how many times 'Baz' appears in the table(this should be done for every name) and display only if the value of count > the 3 for example.

Comment: this sql there is no where clause defining the relation between the two tables director and film.

Comment: how about changing the group by clause to "group by director.LastName+director.FirstName"

Comment: nope,I get an error that director.LastName isn't contained in a group by or an aggregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the name and use a `count()`

```
select name, count(*) as name_count
from your_table
group by name
```

Aggregate functions like `count` are applied **for each group**.

To display only names that appear more than 1 time you can do

```
select name, count(*) as name_count
from your_table
group by name
having count(*) > 1
```

`Having` is like a `where` clause but for groups.

### Edit

```
select d.LastName, d.FirstName, count(f.Id_Director) as counter
from director d
inner join film f on f.Id_Director = d.id 
group by d.LastName, d.FirstName
having count(f.Id_Director) > 2
```

You had grouped by the film too. That won't work. You basically queried for directors that are more than 2 times part of **a film**.

Comment: Nope,this isn't giving me the results I was expecting.I added the piece of code that I'm actually trying to make it work

Comment: Please also example data add expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are grouping by film. Since there are a director/film is ill away count as 1.

You you want to keep the film names in that select result set I suggest you make a select movies and a subquery to count how many times that director can be joined to other movies.

Just writed a example at SQLFiddle
[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d76a/8)